# Make unordered list elements shown at the same height level

Tags: html, css

I am having hard time to put unordered list elements next to each other with the same height in the 'footer' section. I wanted to put the whole code because when I try to run this with only footer, it works fine but it does not work within the whole code. So, I believe rest of the code is affecting it somehow.

I know that this a common problem and the solution is putting display:inline-block. I've tried using display:inline block and float:left but whenever I do that, the list elements disappear.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #4f4d53;
  padding: 30px;
}
.navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.main {
  background-color: #e8be02;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.main li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 75px;
}

.main img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto Black";
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #4f4d53;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Roboto Black";
  font-size: 64px;
  color: #e8be02;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto Black";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #e8be02;
}

h4 {
  font-family: "Roboto Black";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

p {
  font-family: "Roboto Black";
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #4f4d53;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #4f4d53;
}

.careers {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="#home">gtd</a>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <h1>Hello, we’re gtd.</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="media/img_brian_circle.png" alt="img" /></li>
                <li><img src="media/img_danielle_circle.png" alt="img" /></li>
                <li><img src="media/img_lisa_circle.png" alt="img" /></li>
             </ul></div>

        <div class="main-2">
            <h2>How it started</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <div class="careers">
                <ul>
                        <h3>Team</h3>
                        <li><h4>Lisa</h4></li>
                        <li><h4>Danielle</h4></li>
                        <li><h4>Brian</h4></li>
                        <li><h4>Join us!</h4></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="careers">
                <ul>
                        <h3>Learn More</h3>
                        <li><h4>Manifesto</h4></li>
                        <li><h4>Work</h4></li>
                        <li><h4>Stories</h4></li>
                        <li></li>
                </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="careers">
                <ul>
                        <h3>Meet Us</h3>
                        <li><h4>Studio</h4></li>
                        <li><h4>Community</h4></li>
                        <li><h4>Workshop</h4></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="careers">
                <ul>
                        <h3>Contact</h3>
                        <li><h4>Facebook</h3></li>
                        <li><h4>Twitter</h3></li>
                        <li><h4>Youtube</h3></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I'm getting is this

```
Team        
Lisa             Learn MORE         Meet US      Contact
Danielle         Manifesto          Studio       Facebook
Brian            Work               Community    Twitter
Join US!         Stories            Workshop     Youtube
```

What I'd like to get is

```
Team       Learn MORE      Meet US      Contact
Lisa       Manifesto       Studio       Facebook
Danielle   Work            Community    Twitter
Brian      Stories         Workshop     Youtube
Join US!
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

First Way to achieve:

```
.footer{
   display:flex;
}
```

Second way to achieve:

```
.footer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.careers {
    /* display: inline-block; */ /* remove this if you add float:left; */
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: It helped, thanks! Is there anyway I can make this work without using flex via my approach?

Answer (score 0):

to make it even better I would do

```
.footer {
background-color: #4f4d53;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```